# Getting an error for ruby gem dependencies in a custom built gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to ruby and gem creation and we are trying to build a simple gem and I have given the following dependencies in the gemspec:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency "csv"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "fileutils"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "json"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "rest-client"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "openssl"
```

The gem install fails with the following error - Could not find a valid gem 'openssl' (>= 0). The same error occurs for json and rest-client as well but when I do a gem list, I can see the following:

```
csv (3.0.0)
fileutils (1.1.0)
json (2.1.0, default: 2.0.4)
openssl (2.1.1, default: 2.0.5)
rest-client (2.1.0.rc1)
```

I tried a few things like uninstalling the above version of rest-client and installing the version 2.0.2, at which point I no longer see an error for rest-client. Could someone help me on how we can define dependencies which would consider default versions as well as versions like 2.1.0.rc1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Gemfile, as you would in a normal ruby application and add these gems in there. Once this is done, run `bundle install` and re-install the app. This should solve your problem!

Hope this helps,

Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben, we'll probably do that before we release the gem. The plan to eventually share this gem within our company. My question though is why is the gem install failing to recognize the already installed gems which are listed like this - json (2.1.0, default: 2.0.4)
openssl (2.1.1, default: 2.0.5)
rest-client (2.1.0.rc1)

Comment: Did you require them?

Comment: This is just at the gem installation stage, I did require them in the actual code. The install fails to identify any gem which when listed is in the format - "gemname" (version, default: version) or "gemname" (default: version) or any pre-release version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the versions you want to be used? For example:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency "csv"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "fileutils"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "json", "~> 2.04"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "rest-client", "~> 2.1.0.rc1"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "openssl", "~> 2.05"
```

Comment: Yes Peter, I tried that for the gems which have the default versions installed like json and openssl and it still failed but again the intent is to allow users to use our gem and the custom gem is not dependent on any specific versions of these other gems. Whatever way we mention it in the gemspec, it fails to identify a gem which has a default version installed. Another thing I noticed is when I have two version of rest-client (2.1.0.rc1, 2.0.2) then there is no error for rest-client but for json (2.1.0, default: 2.0.4) and openssl (2.1.1, default: 2.0.5), I still get an error.